# How can I play music directly in an app using the Android Spotify SDK?

Tags: android, kotlin, sdk, spotify

I'm currently working with the Android Spotify SDK and I want to play music directly in the app. Right now I can only start music through the Spotify Player:

```
if (mSpotifyAppRemote != null && spotifyUri != null) {
                    spotifyAppRemote.playerApi.play(spotifyUri)
                            .setResultCallback {
                              /...
                            }
```

But I want to play the music in the app. So far I have not found a solution. But there has to be one, because other apps have implemented this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the new Spotify SDK, they are pushing developers to play music through the Spotify app and not in their own apps. Their previous SDK ([which they shut down on November 1st, 2019](https://developer.spotify.com/community/news/2019/09/09/streaming-repo-shutdown-date/)) allowed developers to do that but they have now migrated away from supporting that way. Some repos/packages still exist in trying to support the previous implementation like the [`react-native-spotify` integration](https://github.com/lufinkey/react-native-spotify) but they are facing a similar issue [since the SDK has been removed.](https://github.com/lufinkey/react-native-spotify/issues/142) Apps that still do play music through their own app are now using a deprecated SDK which, although it may still work, is not supported and would require an update if they want to upgrade their apps at all. That is the case with Spotify at least, there may be other music streaming services that allow different controls.